# How to keep a div centered when resizing window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div tab on the right side of the screen in the middle and when I try to resize the window it moves the the bottom right of the screen. I would like to to stay in the middle regardless of screen size. How could I accomplish this with my current code? I've tried margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto but that didn't seem to work. I also can't necessarily change the position: because they need to those to make everything else work.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
      }
      #side-chat {
        position: absolute;
        right: 100%;
        bottom:50%;
        z-index:9999999999999 !important;
        width: 150px;
        margin-right: -59px;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(30, 175, 230, 0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;    
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:99999999999999 !important;
        top: 400px;
        right: -300px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper.chatbox-open {
        right: 0
      }
      #olark-box-wrapper.chatbox-closed {
       right: -300px;
      }
      #habla_window_div {
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      #side-chat img{
        margin-right: 10px;
        
      }
      #side-chat:hover,
      #side-chat:active {
       background: #22a7e5;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="olark-box-wrapper">

  <!-- Olark chat tab -->
    <a id="side-chat" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setTimeout(changeClass, 3);">
      <img src="icon-chat.svg">
         Chat
    </a>

  <!-- Empty Olark chat box container -->
  <div id="olark-box-container"></div>

</div>

<!-- begin olark code -->
<script type="text/javascript" async> ;(function(o,l,a,r,k,y){if(o.olark)return; r="script";y=l.createElement(r);r=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0]; y.async=1;y.src="//"+a;r.parentNode.insertBefore(y,r); y=o.olark=function(){k.s.push(arguments);k.t.push(+new Date)}; y.extend=function(i,j){y("extend",i,j)}; y.identify=function(i){y("identify",k.i=i)}; y.configure=function(i,j){y("configure",i,j);k.c[i]=j}; k=y._={s:[],t:[+new Date],c:{},l:a}; })(window,document,"static.olark.com/jsclient/loader.js");
  /* custom configuration goes here (www.olark.com/documentation) */
  //olark.configure('system.hb_detached', true);
  olark.configure('box.inline', true);
  olark.identify('xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx');</script>
  <!-- end olark code -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    // Javacript function to toggle the class of the chat box wrapper
    function changeClass()
    {
      // Get the HTML object containing the Olark chat box
      var olark_wrapper = document.getElementById("olark-box-wrapper");
      // If the chat box is already open, close id
      if ( olark_wrapper.className.match(/(?:^|\s)chatbox-open(?!\S)/) ) {
        olark_wrapper.className = "chatbox-closed";
        document.querySelector('#side-chat img').src = "icon-chat.svg";
      }
      // Otherwise add open the Olark chat box
      else {        
        olark_wrapper.className = "chatbox-open";
        document.querySelector('#side-chat img').src = "icon-cancel.svg";
        
      }
        
    }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `flex` for that. Just apply `display: flex;`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` to the parent element

Comment: grid can also be of a great help,writing-mode too and  font-size:clamp(x,x,x) could is also something you may want to know about. example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdWQRRB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing your div relatively to the parent using absolute absolute positioning.

If the size of your wrapper is important, you should wrap it on another div, make it have the entire height of the page, position it on the right using  and use a flex display as suggested by @ali-abbasov in your comment.

```
#wrapper-of-olark-box-wrapper {
  position: fixed; // so that it stays positioned as you want regardless of the parent
  top:0;
  right:0;

  height: 100%; // you can try 100vh if this one does not work
  
  display: flex; // the solution
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Doing this prevents the chatbox from opening and closing

Comment: @Shultz I tried with some changes that I wrote in the code, it's working on my side:

https://codepen.io/mlarabi/pen/zYZMNOg